# Sitecore: Hide data template field from page editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, templatefield, page-editor

I have 2 data template fields "title" and "id", used for the HTML page title and the id attribute in the body tag respectively. When the page is viewed using *Page Editor*, Sitecore attempts to render editor controls on these items and because they are outside of the main form tag, controls don't get rendered correctly. I don't need these to be editable in the *Page Editor*.

1. What's the best approach/solution to handle fields like these?
2. Is hiding these 2 template fields from the *Page Editor* a solution?
3. If so, how do you hide the fields from the *Page Editor* and still have it available on the *Content editor* (so we can still edit it within the *Content editor*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Page Editor, all you should need to do is render their values without a FieldRenderer. e.g, bind the field values to a standard .NET control. Or use a scriptlet -- <%=Sitecore.Context.Item["Title"]%>

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I ended up using this:

`<title><%=Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Page Title"]%></title>`

Comment: No problem. Be careful w/ the .Fields collection. As you have it here, probably couldn't cause a NullRef, but if you use the dictionary directly on the item (i.e. Item["Title"]) the worst that you'll get is an empty string.